# How to group e-mails by thread?

Tags: c#, email, imap

I need to recognize if email message is an response for message sent by my application, to put it into same email thread (something like gmail does). How can I mark an email or what data let me to recognize if it's an answer for one of previous messages in a thread?

I'm connecting through IMAP protocol, but I can easily switch to pop3 if it will be easier...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you send your e-mail, include a `Message-ID` header with some globally-unique ID for your message.

When you get the response, it should have a `References` header that refers to your original `Message-ID`.

Answer (score 3):

The **'In-Reply-To'** header of the child should have the value of the **Message-Id** header of the  parent.

There is one another field in header **'References'** which contains message ids of all its parent.

you can user either of them as per your requirement.